# 'major version 51 is newer than 5' in cordova/Mobile First application

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I´m trying to build an [(IBM) MobileFirst](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/) application, which uses cordova.
The requirements are to use jdk 1.7 and Ant 1.9.3, and my environment has it.
When I build it (using *cordova build android*) the console does not generate the apk and the console has this output:

```
[javac] warning: java\net\URL.class(java\net:URL.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded. [javac] warning: java\security\MessageDigest.class(java\security:MessageDigest.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

My config.xml has

```
<preference name="minSdkVersion" value="21" />
```

And I have build tools 23 and 25 installed.

The java -version outputs

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Anyone has any clue of what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The Libraries or framework which you are using in your project are compiled with newer version than java version "1.7.0_80".
So it is will not run on prior version.
You have 2 options.

1. Run your project on java version on which the libraries or framework is compiled.(may be java8).
   OR
2. Find that library compatible to java version "1.7.0_80"

Answer (score 0):

I also had encountered same issue,cordova command `cordova build android` requires java version 1.8.

After setting  JAVA_HOME to jdk 1.8 resolved it for me .

You can download Jdk 1.8 from here [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)